# Regarding Hyperledger Explorer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

I am struggling to connect Blockchain Explorer to a custom network(Or to Block Acivity Page) that I created with Fabric configure  Hyperledger Explorer.
My problem is to write correctly all info in the connection.json file. Can somebody help me by providing a very simple example of connection.json for a custom ntework deployed on a single node with 4 peer (BOFN network UP)?

Please help on this .

Comment: BOFN Up or byfn up ?

Comment: byfn up only. Spelling mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have a great example in the Blockchain Explorer Github [page](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/blob/master/app/platform/fabric/config.json). Should work perfectly with the fabric sample first network tutorial (./byfn.sh), you just need to change all path files in the config.json to your fabric-sample/crypto-config/ directory. Think you can ignore the credentialStore path (and cryptoStore path). For example:

```
  "adminPrivateKey": {
    "path": "fabric-path/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore"
  },
```

Could Be:

```
  "adminPrivateKey": {
    "path": "/home/kalai/Desktop/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore"
  },
```

And do it for all key-value path

Comment: Thanks  Alex. Actually the Set up is done. It's working. But I want to change the chaincode name instead of  mycc(Blockchain Explorer default). I have changed my chaged my chain code name & Path . It's not working.

Comment: Okey, if mycc its not your chaincode name when you installed and instantiated it, use this command:
`sudo  updatedb`
Hyperledger Explorer use the `locate` command to find your chaincode in your system, locate use the database filesystem to search files. With updatedb you will update the database and locate can find the correct path and name of the file. This solution only works on linux systems.

Comment: Thank you Alex. I will try this. I am getting this below error